# iPhone private API of canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace and didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

I want to ask a questions about the `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace` and `ddidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`. Are they private API iPhone application?

If yes, how can I modify it? And after I modify the private API of iPhone, will the iPhone reject my application?

If no, where should I put the modified code? I used to put the code within a .m file, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

They are both documented in Apples documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com:80/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1) So they shouldn't be private. Usually finding private API's takes some investigative work and yes Apple will almost always reject an App if it uses a private API (There has been one case I have heard of that they let it through) but you shouldn't run into troubles with those ones.

Comment: thank you for your reply. How can I call the delegate method? I used to add a statement 'NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request_get2 delegate:self];', request_get2 is NSHTTPURLRequest type. However, the above functions are called after the error message. Would you mind to help me to see about the code I wrote?

Comment: What error msgs are you getting? Are you building the request correctly and implementing all the NSURLConnection delegate methods like connection: didReceiveData and connectionDidFinishLoading? Also I've only ever used NSMutableURLRequest, haven't looked at NSHTTPURLRequest

Comment: thank you for your reply. This is the question about the NSHTTPURLRequest I asked and I also post the code and error in the post. If you feel free, please give me some comment. Thank you.

Comment: There are no errors in your original question other than "it did not work". Please put either some code or the error thats thrown to be able to help. Have a look at the demo code on the link above, it might help you with your own work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to looking in the documentation for a method (if it's there it isn't private), you can also use [App Scanner](http://www.chimpstudios.com/appscanner/) to search specifically for private API method signatures.  It also allows you to scan your .app before submitting it to the review team.